# When to use ExecuteScalar, ExecuteReader, and ExecuteNonQuery?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am confused with the usage of

1. ExecuteScalar
2. ExecuteReader
3. ExecuteNonQuery

when executing SQL queries in my code. When should I use each of these methods?

Answer (score 69):

- `ExecuteScalar()` only returns the value from the first column of the first row of your query.
- `ExecuteReader()` returns an object that can iterate over the entire result set while only keeping one record in memory at a time.
- `ExecuteNonQuery()` does not return data at all: only the number of rows affected by an insert, update, or delete.

Additionally, you can look at the `DbDataAdapter` type, which includes a `Fill()` method that allows you to download the **entire result set** into a `DataTable` or `DataSet` object, as well as a number of other abilities.

Finally, this seems like a good time for you to get familiar with [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/). This is what documentation is made for: you have the method names; go look them up.

Comment: It's important to note that when using **ExecuteNonQuery**  additionally to get the number of rows affected by an insert, update, or delete it's possible to get output value (of course only if the SP contain output params).

Comment: Actually, ExecuteNonQuery will return an integer result with the number of rows affected. You don't need to specify an output parameter.

Comment: MSDN's link is dead.

Comment: The link still takes you to the right place. It was always just for the front page of the documentation area.

Answer (score 48):

**ExecuteScalar** : For Single Value

```
 Int32 Value = Convert.ToInt32(ExecuteScalar("SELECT SUM(COLUMNNAME) FROM TABLE")); 
 Int32 Value = Convert.ToInt32(ExecuteScalar("SELECT AVG(COLUMNNAME) FROM TABLE"));
```

**ExecuteReader** : Row reading in forward mode

```
 IdataReader dr = ExecuteReader("SELECT * FROM TABLE"); 
 while(dr.Read())
 {
     //You will get rows values like this dr["ColumnName"]
 }
```

**ExecuteNonQuery** : For Inserting/Deleting/Updating the rows into table

```
ExecuteNonQuery("DELETE FROM TABLE");
ExecuteNonQuery("UPDATE TABLE SET COLUMNNAME = 'A'");
```

Answer (score 10):

## [What is the difference between ExecuteReader, ExecuteNonQuery and ExecuteScalar](http://dng-ado.blogspot.com/2007/05/what-is-difference-between.html)

**ExecuteNonQuery**

> ExecuteNonQuery method will return number of rows effected with
> INSERT, DELETE or UPDATE operations. This ExecuteNonQuery method will
> be used only for insert, update and delete, Create, and SET
> statements. [(Read More about ExecuteNonQuery)](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/09/executenonquery-example-in-aspnet-using.html)

[SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**ExecuteReader**

> Execute Reader will be used to return the set of rows, on execution of
> SQL Query or Stored procedure using command object. This one is
> forward only retrieval of records and it is used to read the table
> values from first to last.[(Read More about ExecuteReader)](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/09/sqlcommand-executereader-example-in.html)

[SqlCommand.ExecuteReader MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**Execute Scalar**

> Execute Scalar will return single row single column value i.e. single
> value, on execution of SQL Query or Stored procedure using command
> object. It’s very fast to retrieve single values from database. ([Read
> More about Execute Scalar](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/09/executescalar-example-in-aspnet-using-c.html))

[SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

Use `ExecuteScalar` when your query returns a single value. If it returns more results, then the end result is the first column of the first row. An example might be `SELECT Count(*) from MyTable`

Use `ExecuteReader` for getting result set with multiple rows/columns (e.g., `SELECT col1, col2 from MyTable`.

Use `ExecuteNonQuery` for SQL statements which will not retrieve results from database but make updation in existing database (e.g., `UPDATE, INSERT,` etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Essentially this is simplified, but you can look up each of the SQL terms or .net objects or read about ADO.net on MSDN for more info.

`ExecuteScalar` when you call an SQL scalar function that just returns a single number.

`ExecuteReader` when you are making an SQL call that will return a record set from a table, which gives you an SqlDataReader object to retrieve the data in C#.

`ExecuteNonQuery` is used when there is no return value of any kind expected from SQL server, an example being a simple UPDATE statement.