# How to check if Data on column still exist using VB.Net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have datatable `tblEmployeeInfo` and column `EmployeeName` with contains data.

```
EmployeeName
Mike              
Jay
Paul
```

Also I have `Textbox1` to type a name and button to "Verify".
How do I check if the Employee Name exists in the column `EmployeeName`?

For example, "Jay".

So far this is my code on button "Verify":

```
    conn.Open()
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [Employee Name] FROM tblHolidayOvertimeEntry WHERE [Employee Name] = '" & tbEmployeeName.Text & "' "
    Dim result1 as String = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
    conn.Close()


    If result1 <> tbEmployeeName.Text Then

        MsgBox("No Employee Name found")
    Else

        MsgBox("Employee name still exist")

    End If
```

Comment: Gah! The sql injection vulnerability. It burns us!

Comment: Think about what you're doing. Why would you call `ExecuteNonQuery` to execute a query? If you've done any reading on ADO.NET, which you should have done before posting here, then you know that there are basically three ways to execute a query: call `Fill` on a data adapter, call `ExecuteReader` on a command and call `ExecuteScalar` on a command.  Decide which is appropriate to your case and do it.

Comment: That has not been the right way to create SQL for a long time now.

Comment: Sorry guyz it is my first time. Please help me.

Comment: I sure hope that Jay's full name isn't Jay O' Drop Table

Answer (score 0):

first of all clear concept about  ExecuteScalar, ExecuteReader and ExecuteNonQuery from this link:
[When to use ExecuteScalar,ExecuteReader,ExecuteNonQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058970/when-to-use-executescalar-executereader-executenonquery)

and you have to set like

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [Employee Name] FROM tblHolidayOvertimeEntry WHERE [Employee Name] = '" & tbEmployeeName.Text & "' "
Dim result1 as String = cmd.ExecuteScalar
```