# I Want to get id from select query in C# but every time i run the program, The query returns me "-1"

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying To get ID against selected name in Drop Down list by using select query but it always returns the value "-1" instead of relevant result.

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = con.CreateCommand();
cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd2.CommandText = "Select Pid From Provinces where Pname = '" + pr + "'";
cmd2.CommandText = "Select Pid From Provinces where Pname = '" + prov.Text + "'";
int pid = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Did you try your query to your DB itself?

Comment: Among these two which one you want to execute? any how second one is going to be executed, beware of Injection

Comment: Have you want to return exactly only one PID from that query or return count of PIDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me add few notes for you before answer the question, You should aware about the usage of ExecuteNonQuery, and why other peoples refer ExecuteScalar for you. here is the difference you have to note.

- **ExecuteNonQuery()** does not return data at all: only the number of rows affected by an insert, update, or delete
- **ExecuteScalar()** only returns the value from the first column of the first row of your query.

There is few more things I want to remind you, As a developer we won't give the key to hackers through [SqlInjection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp), for that we should use parameterization like the following:

```
using(SqlCommand cmdSql = con.CreateCommand())
{
    cmdSql.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmdSql.CommandText = "Select Pid From Provinces where Pname =@Pname";
    cmdSql.Parameters.Add("@Pname ", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value= prov.Text;
    int pid = Convert.ToInt32(cmdSql.ExecuteScalar());
}
```

Comment: Thanks For help Now its working properly.

Comment: @AbdulBasitMehmood: If it really helps means, mark it as accepted

Answer (score 4):

You need to use ExecuteScalar instead of ExecuteNonQuery

```
int pid = Convert.ToInt32(cmd2.ExecuteScalar());
```

For more details please refer [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058970/when-to-use-executescalar-executereader-executenonquery)

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that `ExecuteNonQuery` doesn't return the database **value** when using a `Select` command - It returns a **return code** for success or failure.

If you want to read the database value, use the following code. **Note** that I used an `SqlParameter` instead of your parameter concatenation, which can cause SQL injections and is a poor practice:

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = con.CreateCommand();
cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd2.CommandText = "Select Pid From Provinces where Pname=@pr";
cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("pr", pr));
int result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd2.ExecuteScalar());
```

---

Alternativly, you can use fill a `DataTable` with multiple results:

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = con.CreateCommand();
cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd2.CommandText = "Select Pid From Provinces where Pname=@pr";
cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("pr", pr));

SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);

// Create a new datatable which will hold the query results:
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

Connection.Open();

// Fill a datatable with the query results:
adp.Fill(dt);

Connection.Close();
```